# Invalidate Ribbon: how in Outlook VSTO 4

Tags: .net, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm trying to enable/disable buttons during my VSTO 4 Outlook 365/2016 AddIn. **It's not a XML code, but "pure .NET"**.

It seems the Invalidade() method does only apply when the TAB-Ribbon IS NOT already shown.

I mean, if I try to enable/disable buttons at the StartUp code (I'm handling the Message events for "Read/Open" and "New"), I've gotten no success.

But, after the TAB be displayed (and all buttons are enabled), if I press some of them and Invalidate(Control), everything goes right.

Questions:

- Is there any way to invalidate buttons without force user to press a button?
- If not, is there any way to force the display of my TAB and Invalidate() some controls then?

I appreciate any help.

**UPDATE**

That is my code in VB.NET:

```
Private WithEvents Inspectores As Outlook.Inspectors


Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup


    Inspectores = Me.Application.Inspectors
    AddHandler Inspectores.NewInspector, AddressOf MessageActivity

End Sub



Friend Sub MessageActivity(ByVal Item As Object)


    Dim Status As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(Item.currentitem, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)


    If TypeOf Status Is MailItem Then

        If Status IsNot Nothing Then
            Try
                If Status.EntryID Is Nothing Then
                    AddHandler Status.Open, AddressOf NewingMessage
                Else
                    AddHandler Status.Read, AddressOf ReadingMessage
                End If

            Catch ex As system.Exception
                MsgBox(ex.message)
            End Try

        End If

    End If

End Sub


Sub ReadingMessage()

    Dim ribbonCollection As ThisRibbonCollection = Globals.Ribbons _
   (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector())


    'MsgBox("Opening")

    IsNotReallyNew = True

    ribbonCollection.Ribbon1.ObkRead.Enabled = True
    ribbonCollection.Ribbon1.Button1.Enabled = False
    ribbonCollection.Ribbon1.btnSign.Enabled = False
    ribbonCollection.Ribbon1.btnEncode.Enabled = False
    ribbonCollection.Ribbon1.Button3.Enabled = False

    ribbonCollection.Ribbon1.RibbonUI.Invalidate()

End Sub
```

Comment: So are you saying Outlook is not invoking the callback specified in your ribbon manifest when you call Invalidate?

Comment: It's invoking normally (I can see this in Debug mode) but since neither the message isn't still opened nor any of its Ribbons (including my own), simply the Ribbon does not assume the new status. It seems Invalidate() just functions with an "already visible" Ribbon...

Comment: Have you tried to call Invalidate from the Inspector.Activate event handler?

Comment: Hmmm... really no. I don't know how handle this Event. Can you post a sample please?  I will update my post to show the code I'm using now.

Comment: When Application.Inspectors.NewInspector event fires, grab the Inspector passed as the parameter and set an event handler on it.

Comment: I don't know how do it. Please, hold on some few minutes to show what I'm doing here (some translations in code shall be required).

Comment: What is the problem? You have the MessageAcivity2 event handler above (that name certainly won't win you any prizes), just call Invalidate from there.

Comment: It does not function - simple as this. No error but when the Ribbon comes to screen, the disabled buttons are still enabled...   :) Typo.

Comment: By the time NewInspector fires, MailItem.Open has already fired. Try to run your code in the MessageActivity event handler.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, MessageActivity is fired before the message windows is already shown. That's the problem!  And curiously, even if after this the routines is called, no action is performed in fact.  BUT, if I attach the same routine to a button of the same Ribbon, everything functions like a charm.